# Flash push item inside of an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

Im needing some help in AS#3 and arrays
Basically i am having trouble of pushing items into a 2D array with errors.
Below is what i have and trying to use:

```
    var j = 0
    var i = 0
    var mixerArray:Array = new array();
    function Mixer()
    {
    optionLenght = gridOption.sequence_txt.text;// == 8
    track_list = gridOption.track_text.text;// == 4


    for (j = 0; j <track_list; j++)
    {
    make_tracks();
     for (i = 0; i <optionLenght; i++)
    {
       item_inside_track();
    }
    }

   function make_tracks(){
   tracks = new Tracks();//a large box
   MixerArray[j].push(tracks);
   }
   /* Make little boxes inside big box
   ..................................................
   */
   function item_inside_track(){
   box= new Box();//littlebox
   MixerArray[j][i].push(box); // iwant to push this box into track[j]
    }
```

basically im trying to create an array that stores values inside of values for example

```
   MixerArray()
   [0]TRACK1  =  [0]//littlebox ,[1]//littlebox, [2]//littlebox [3]//littlebox etc to 8
   [1]TRACK2  =  [0]//littlebox ,[1]//littlebox, [2]//littlebox [3]//littlebox etc to 8
   [2]TRACK3  = [0]//littlebox ,[1]//littlebox, [2]//littlebox [3]//littlebox etc to 8
   [3]TRACK4  = [0]//littlebox ,[1]//littlebox, [2]//littlebox [3]//littlebox etc to 8
```

This has to be dynamic, as it will constant change..i have cut the addchilds and other code to minimize it to the source area.

Comment: I can see many errors in this code, what do you get in your console?

Comment: MixerArray[j][i].push(box); this line errors, saids that this is not a function

Comment: Does your Tracks class actually have a function called `push()`? If not, that is the issue right there. MixerArray[j][i] (user lowercase, camelcase btw) is of type `Tracks`, not `Array`. So unless Tracks extends array or you added in a custom function called push, there is no push function.

Comment: no it doesnt have push(); i understand that but i dont know how to add  the box inside of the array:  myarray.push.muMC;//works but myarray[0][1].push(box);; throws errors

Comment: picture this:  myarray.push(tracks);myarray[tracks1].push(mymovieclip);  trace(myarray[0][0]); // tracks, movieclip.

Comment: It throws error because the function does not exist. You cannot access something that does not exist. If you want to add it to an array in your `Tracks` class, make the array public and access it like `myarray[0][1].arrayName.push(box)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're basically creating an array of arrays.
The problem here is that you're trying to push items into an element of the second array.

```
MixerArray[j][i].push(box); // iwant to push this box into track[j]
```

If you want to push into the J array, you just have to do this:

```
MixerArray[j].push(box);
```

However, you need to create the different Arrays contained in MixerArray first. Just push new Arrays into MixerArray in an initialisation function or at the start of your first function . Another issue with your code is that you used:

```
var mixerArray:Array = new array();
```

while in the rest of your code you're using:

```
MixerArray
```

Make the changes and tell me if it works !

Comment: MixerArray[j] = new array (); i needed to add a new array before adding the items inside of it